# Undefined name 'Permission' for permission_handler package in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

Trying to write a permission code for camera and microphone on flutter

I'm currently using permission_handler: ^5.0.1 and have imported the package after adding the dependency in pubspec.yaml

```
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';
```

But when I used the following code,

```
await Permission.camera.request();
```

I have the following error.

> Undefined name 'Permission'.  Try correcting the name to one that is defined, or defining the name.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I realized later that the error was because I accidentally deleted permission_handler_platform_interface-2.0.2 in my external packages inside the External Libraries > Dart Packages in Flutter SDK.

I resolved it by running

```
flutter pub cache repair
```

Answer (score 0):

Try read the docs again. Maybe they have change the code or maybe make sure that you have get the package.